# Change position of Direction Render when drag Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, direction

I have a project that save waypoints on the database according with the Marker position, I want to use custom icons on this markers so I supressed the Route Markers (the green markers)

But if I move the marker to another point it will not change the render line according with the marker position, I want to "update" this renderer when I change my marker position.

[This is the link to my project with the original version](http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/indexRotasTeste002.htm)
Here is my code: (Edited with my try)

```
var map, ren, ser;
var data = {};
var data2 = {};
var marker;
var infowindow;
var directionsDisplay;

var wayA = [];
var wayB = [];
var directionResult = [];

function goma()
{
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mappy');   
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,       
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.563594, -46.654239),
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map( mapDiv, mapOptions );

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        if (wayA.length == wayB.length) {
        wayA.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,      
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map        
        }));
        } else {
        wayB.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,  
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map  
        }));  

ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true, suppressMarkers : true}  );
    ren.setMap(map);
    ren.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    ser.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].getPosition(), 'destination':  wayB[wayB.length-1].getPosition(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK') {
                    directionResult.push(res);
                    ren.setDirections(res); 

                } else {
                    directionResult.push(null);
                }
        });     
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a [demo](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/davie/fredslatest.html) which does what you are looking for.

The changes you require are in

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {
'map': map,
'preserveViewport': true,
'draggable':true/*, 
'suppressMarkers' : true */} 
);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();    
    }
});
```

Notice `suppressMarkers' : true` has been commented out

This means that the origonal markers are still there when the direction markers are displayed. These are removed using

```
function clearOverlays() {
 if (wayA) {
   for (i in wayA) {
   wayA[i].setMap(null);
 }
 }
 if (wayB) {
   for (i in wayB) {
     wayB[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
}
```

This is called at the end of

```
  function calcRoute() {

directionsService.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].getPosition(), 'destination': 
      wayB[wayB.length-1].getPosition(), 'travelMode': 
 google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(response,status) {
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionResult.push(response);
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);  

            } else {
                directionResult.push(null);
            }

})
clearOverlays();
}
```

Comment: The demo url is not working anymore. I am also looking for similar solution. Further details of my issue is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441938/change-drag-route-with-custom-marker-drag-google-maps-api . Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This map:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_icons_draggable.html

Allows you to drag the markers and recalculates the route based on the new position.  It was developed before "draggable directions" so the polyline is not draggable.

Comment: I tryied but I can't understand the code, look similar but I cant find what I need to change. But thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener function on the markers for 'dragend', which recalculates the direction.  Here's a quick example with identical listeners on each, but you could probably factor this code out into its own function which operates on both wayA and wayB markers.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(wayA[wayA.length-1], 'dragend', function() {
    ser.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].getPosition(), 'destination':  wayB[wayB.length-1].getPosition(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK') {
            rectionResult.push(res);
            ren.setDirections(res); 
        } else  {
            directionResult.push(null);
        }
    })
}

google.maps.event.addListener(wayB[wayB.length-1], 'dragend', function() {
    ser.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].getPosition(), 'destination':  wayB[wayB.length-1].getPosition(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK') {
            rectionResult.push(res);
            ren.setDirections(res); 
        } else  {
            directionResult.push(null);
        }
    })
}
```